# javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream for android

Tags: java, android, audio

Has anyone achieved to make an android version of the class javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream ?
I have already a project written in java with classes that use or even extend this class and I  want to convert it for android. If you have any tips on how I could implement this class or even make something equivalent, please inform me.